# Angular primeNg Table add action buttons to the end of selectable row

Tags: angular, html-table, row, primeng

I work on an angular application with PrimeNG. I have a p-table with single select on (example on stack blitz : [table select demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo)).

**What i want to do :** Add at the end of each row an icon button to redirect the user to a new page.

**The problem :** When i click on the icon button, the row is also selected (and open something else in addition of the new page created by the icon button).

Ideally, the row is selectable, but not on the last column (where the icon button is).
I have quickly created a stackblitz with the issue, tell me if you need more infos:

[stackblitz with the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-uc3x5e)

Comment: ive forked and edited your stackblitz. If i understood correctly you need action button which not 'bubbles' up the event. You need event.stopPropagation() . You can search and read more about 'event bubbling' in google

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-vkohhk?file=src/app/app.component.ts